# Give Properties to a shapefile to be used by another person

Tags: qgis, vector

I have bedrock geoology data. I want to classify the data so it appears with the same propeerties as it does on the suppliers website.

Is there a way i can attribute a property to a layer (in this instance colour) so that when i add the layer to another project it has the same properties.

In essence can someone send me a copied style?

Working in qgis 1.8.0

Comment: I think a .qml with the same name as the Shapefile should do the trick. Use "save style" to create the qml.

Comment: Cheers. Never thought of it. Well kind of did half way through the question but was not sure. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Underdark said above it is the qml file.